# Is it OK to use the USB 5v pin as power source?

Tags: usb, computers, computer-architecture, motherboard

I am doing some stuff in my case and I need a power source for one LED from inside my case.

I looked up and there are two +5v pins on a USB header inside my case. Is it OK to use them as power source? Can it handle sustained usage?

Comment: Better use a LAN Hub,they are cheap than latop hubs.Guarantees safety,the one without over-current are usually very cheap,so if you blow up no hard feelings.

Comment: What level of current do you require? To fully play by the rules you need to enumerate and request the current you require.  That said if you are taking 100mA or less I do not see any problem in practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usage that is within the USB spec and you wired it correctly, yes.

Normally that means 100 mA without negotiation, 500 mA with (though the distinction is rarely enforced), and potentially more in some follow-on versions.

The answer would ultimately depend on the type of LED utlized - your common small indicator ones typically should be run with 20 mA or less (you did use a resistor, right?).

But if you are talking some sort of LED illumination light or adapted flashlight, then quite possibly you are stressing components beyond their designed capability.

Doing something like putting a huge LED (or parallel array) directly on a port and counting on the port's likely but not certain resettable polyfuse protection feature (or any pre-trip resistance of it) as the current limit would be a very bad idea.

Comment: Yeah it's just a small LED (spec say 20-30mA) and a 100ohm resistor

Comment: Depending on the forward voltage of your LED, that resistor may be slightly smaller than you want - not for the USB port, but for the longetivity of the LED.

Comment: I know I should use a 330ohm but the resistors I have are all round 10s like 10, 100, 1k and I don't want to chain three 100s. It's temporary anyway.

Comment: I recommend using the 1k resistors. Most LEDs will be bright enough unless you need them to be visible in direct sunlight.

Comment: 1K is going to mean 3-4 milliamps, which realistically is a bit dim, especially for something on a computer case.

Answer (score 0):

you could drive anything below 0.5A from the internal or external USB port. Some Motherboards even offer 1A "Charging" Ports, but I cant really tell you how the story is there.

Comment: For USB 1 and 2 the regular setting is max 1 "bin" of power (100mAmp at +5v). For more you need to speak the USB protocol and kindlask if you may be allowed more. (up to 5x more). The host is allowed to say "No". That means 100mAmp is max you can safely draw with a LED and a resistor.